# Вставка текста на место курсора и управление курсором EdixText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Здравствуйте!

У меня в программе имеется окно для ввода СМС сообщения. Мне нужно реализовать вставку смайлика в текст, на место курсора. В интернете ничего путного не нашел. Смайлик в текстовом формате, никаких заморочек.

Кроме того у меня еще есть вопрос по поводу смены места курсора в EditText. Как его двигать программно? Если сохранить не отправленное сообщение из EditText в преференсы, а потом загрузить обратно, то курсор встает на первую позицию. Мне нужно его отправить на другую позицию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 вставку смайлика в текст
```

ее, обычно вставляют его текстовый алиен, например - (smile)

> Как его двигать программно?

гугли варианты по запросу textview cursor position

Comment: Второй вопрос закрыт, спасибо! Не думал, что это делается выделением.

А по первому я что-то не понял. У меня сделано так - при нажатии на кнопку вылезает окно со смайлами. При выборе смайла активность посылает обратно его текстовое значение, которое тупо должно вставиться в текст.

Comment: посылает его - это кого? картинку целую? или имя? тег? 

ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, resId);
text.setSpan(is, index, index + strLength, 0);



можно вставить так, но тебе же надо будет передать его на другую сторону, потому лучше брать тег или имя, что бы передать его и на другой стороне подставить картинку

Comment: Все уже разобрался. Смайл вставляется просто в виде текста пока, заменять его картинкой пока не требуется, но на будущее сохраню. Спасибо.